# sentry-sentry-symfony won't install on Symfony 2.8 due to symfony/http-kernel dependency

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sentry

I have a Symfony 2.8 project on which I'm trying to install sentry/sentry-symfony. To do this I'm running "composer require sentry/sentry-symfony".

From what I understand this sentry library is compatible with Symfony 2.x but it looks like it's requiring symfony/http-kernel 3 or above.

My composer.json file has the following...

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "~2.4",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^3.7",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.0"
    },
```

And this is what happens when I try to do composer require...

```
composer require sentry/sentry-symfony
Using version ^2.2 for sentry/sentry-symfony
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for sentry/sentry-symfony ^2.2 -> satisfiable by sentry/sentry-symfony[2.2.0].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - sentry/sentry-symfony 2.2.0 requires symfony/http-kernel ^3.0||^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13, v4.0.14, v4.0.15, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.2].
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.0.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.0.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.0.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.0.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.0.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.0.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.0.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.0.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.0.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.10 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.11 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.12 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.13 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.14 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.15 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.16 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.17 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.18 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.5 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.6 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.7 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.8 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.3.9 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.10 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.11 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.12 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.13 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.14 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.15 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.16 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.17 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.18 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.19 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.20 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.21 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.5 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.6 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.7 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.8 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v3.4.9 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.10 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.11 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.12 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.13 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.14 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.15 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.5 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.6 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.7 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.8 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.0.9 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.1.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.1.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.1.10 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.1.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.1.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.1.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.1.5 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.1.6 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.1.7 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.1.8 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.1.9 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.2.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.2.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.2.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v2.8.49, required as 2.8.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.49].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Sentry 2.x with Symfony 2.x.

From [documentation](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-symfony#maintained-versions) :

> 2.x is actively maintained on the master branch, but it requires Symfony 3+ and PHP 7.1+;
>
> 1.x is still supported to allow Symfony 2 and PHP 5.6/7.0; it may receive backports of features from the master branch, but it's not guaranteed

To install the version 1.x, use

```
composer require sentry/sentry-symfony "<2"
```

This will install the lastest version **below** 2